# Bluetooth response time

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm want to making a game that would involve N number of android phones connected by bluetooth.

The game is suppose to be a reactor game (like the one you can find on android market, but I want to make it playable on multiple phones), so it is important for me to know who pressed the button first and my question is: is it possible to do it with bluetooth?

I planed it to be like this: user1 will open the game and open a "new game" and all of the other user would open the game in their phone and join this "new game" and when everyone has joined user1 would start the game.
Every time someone presses the button (you know how this game works...) a signal would be sent to the main phone (to user1), but when it is sent there is a delay before the main phone gets it and when user1 clicks there is no delay because it doesn't have to send the signal. How would I eliminate this difference?

I actually don't have any experience with bluetooth and only little experience with android programing, so if there is someone who has some free time to help me you can see my email address on my profile.

Thanks